# Find Google Cloud Platform Operations Performed by a User

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud, audit-logging

Is there a way to track what Google Cloud Platform operations were performed by a user? We want to audit our costs and track usage accordingly.

**Edit**: there's a Cloud SDK (`gcloud`) command:

```sh
compute operations list
```

that lists actions taken on Compute Engine instances.  Is there a way to see what user performed these actions?

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by gcloud? gcloud as you tagged here is a command line tool for managing resources on Google Cloud Platform (GCP).

Comment: We have users running jobs on dataproc, creating compute nodes, etc. There's a gcloud command line function called "compute operations list" that shows the list of actions taken on certain nodes. Is there a way to see what user performed these actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to only track Google Cloud Project (GCP) Compute Engine (GCE) operations with the `list` command for the `operations` subgroup, you are able to use the `--filter` flag to see operations performed by a given user `$GCE_USER_NAME`:

```sh
gcloud compute operations list \
--filter="user=$GCE_USER_NAME" \
--limit=1 \
--sort-by="~endTime"

#=>

NAME                         TYPE   TARGET                      HTTP_STATUS  STATUS  TIMESTAMP
$GCP_COMPUTE_OPERATION_NAME  start  $GCP_COMPUTE_INSTANCE_NAME  200          DONE    1970-01-01T00:00:00.001-00:00
```

**Note**: feeding the string `"~endTime"` into the `--sort-by` flag puts the most recent GCE operation **first**.

It *might* help to retrieve the entire log object in JSON:

```sh
gcloud compute operations list \
--filter="user=$GCE_USER_NAME" \
--format=json \
--limit=1 \
--sort-by="~endTime"

#=>

[
  {
    "endTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.001-00:00",
    . . .
    "user": "$GCP_COMPUTE_USER"
  }
]
```

or YAML:

```sh
gcloud compute operations list \
--filter="user=$GCE_USER_NAME" \
--format=yaml \
--limit=1 \
--sort-by="~endTime"

#=>

---
endTime: '1970-01-01T00:00:00.001-00:00'
. . .
user: $GCP_COMPUTE_USER
```

---

You are also able to use the Cloud SDK (`gcloud`) to explore *all* audit logs, not just audit logs for GCE; it is incredibly clunky, as the other existing answer points out.  However, for anyone who wants to use `gcloud` instead of the console:

```sh
gcloud logging read \
'logName : "projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NAME/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com"
 protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail="GCE_USER_NAME"
 severity>=NOTICE' \
--freshness="1d" \
--limit=1 \
--order="desc" \
--project=$GCP_PROJECT_NAME

#=>

---
insertId: . . .
. . .
protoPayload:
  '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog
  authenticationInfo:
    principalEmail: $GCP_COMPUTE_USER
  . . .
. . .
```

The `read` command defaults to YAML format, but you can also get your audit logs in JSON:

```sh
gcloud logging read \
'logName : "projects/$GCP_PROJECT_NAME/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com"
 protoPayload.authenticationInfo.principalEmail="GCE_USER_NAME"
 severity>=NOTICE' \
--format=json \
--freshness="1d" \
--limit=1 \
--order="desc" \
--project=$GCP_PROJECT_NAME

#=>

[
  {
    . . .
    "protoPayload": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
      "authenticationInfo": {
        "principalEmail": "$GCE_USER_NAME"
      },
      . . .
    },
    . . .
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can't see a list of `gcloud` commands executed, you can see a list of API actions. `gcloud beta logging` surface help with listing/reading logs, but via the console it's a bit harder to use. Try checking the logs on the [cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer).